# How to set the linespacing=2(doublespacing) using \fontsize{<size>}{<size>}\selectfont

Tags: fonts, fontspec, fontsize

I want to change the spacing to doublespacing using the `\fontsize{<size>}{<size>}\selectfont` to be more flexible for different font sizes.

## example one using 12pt font size

```
\fontsize{12pt}{<size>}\selectfont
```

## example two using 11pt font size

```
\fontsize{11pt}{<size>}\selectfont
```

What are the `\baselineskip` corresponding to `\doublespacing` in the above to examples?

Comment: If you set \baselinestretch to 2 (which is more than double spacing) then the baseline is doubled at every `\fontsize` automatically so it isn't clear what else you need? eg use `setspace` package and specify doublespacing.